# Entry in Timatic when travelling with a German Blue Pass (convention travel document)

Tags: refugees, german-residents

If a passenger has a German blue travel document under Convention of 28 July 1951 and the nationality stated on the document is Somalia, do I have to fill in Somalia or Germany in the nationality field for Timatic?

Comment: If you hold a 1951 Convention travel document, you should indicate the nationality stated on the document. However, with these less common travel documents, iatatravelcenter at least sometimes give incorrect or incomprehensible results.